# Is there a way to stack two words in one cell of a HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table

Im trying to stack two words on each other in a single cell in a table, but I couldn't quite find a answer.

Im trying to get something like this,

[image]

but I keep getting this,

[image]

Here is the line of code - `<th bgcolor='#ffe598' text-align= 'center'>Social Studies</th>`
This is meant for a table, and not just a plain line of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<br>`. A line break. You can view some documentation on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to add a hardcoded linebreak `<br>`

```css
th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Social<br> Studies</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or create lines with span elements and make those elements blocks like:

```css
th {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span>Social</span>
      <span>Studies</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```